# How can I separate this date time column into different columns?

Tags: r, string, lubridate

I am currently trying to separate my date and time data into seperate columns.

My data is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a.m (or p.m). What I need to do is separate the date and time into 2 separate columns. Then subset my date into day, month and year. I also want to convert the time into a 24 hour time. I have tried using strsplit, as.Date, many many others but I still cannot get my data to a point that I can actually do anything with it. There has just been countless errors.

To make things understandable, my date and time column of data is inside a larger dataset. The heading for this column of information required is 'Date_Time'. In this column an example date would be '17/09/2019 9:15:27 a.m.'. As you can imagine it is incredibly frustrating trying to work with this.

What I ideally want is...

day  month  year  time
17    9     2019  09:15:27

...whilst still preserving the original Date_Time column

Comment: you can use `strsplit` or if you want to use `lubridate` then define the `format`.

Comment: I have tried using strsplit and lubridate and defining the format, but I am fairly novice with R so I may have been using it incorrectly

Comment: if `s <- "17/09/2019 9:15:27 a.m."`, then `day <- substr(s,1,2) , month <- substr(s,4,5)` This is crude but effective method.

Comment: Okay, will give that a go and see how that works now. I will need to apply this to a whole dataset though

Comment: If you want to stick to `strsplit` then this might help `strsplit(s, "/|\\s+")`. But then you have to tag first, second and third part of split to columns you want to create.

Comment: Unsure what this means^

Comment: You get this out of string, each separated `"17"      "09"      "2019"    "9:15:27" "a.m."`, from `strsplit(s, "/|\\s+")`. To extract first part `strsplit(s, "/|\\s+")[[1]][1]`. And you will get `"17"`.

Comment: I have been using the crude example you gave, and that has worked so far, would I just need to use rbind to attach them all together in one data frame

Comment: You need to paste some data.

Comment: `'^(\\d{,2})/(\\d{,2})/(\\d{4})\\s+(\\d{,2}\\:\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}).*'` regex for four groups is working with gsub in my case

Comment: I'd recommend using the lubridate package over strsplit and use its `day()`, `month()` and `year()` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it into `POSIXct` and use then `format` to extract day, month, year and time.

```
x <- c("17/09/2019 9:15:27 a.m.", "17/09/2019 9:15:27 p.m.")
x <- gsub("\\.", "", x) #Remove the . in a.m.
x <- as.POSIXct(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") #convert to POSIX
data.frame(day   = format(x, "%d"), 
           month = format(x, "%m"),
           year  = format(x, "%Y"),
           time  = format(x, "%T"))
#  day month year     time
#1  17    09 2019 09:15:27
#2  17    09 2019 21:15:27
```

In case only splitting up into columns is enough, I would use `strsplit` and split on `/` or  .

```
x <- c("17/09/2019 9:15:27 a.m.", "17/09/2019 9:15:27 p.m.")
do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, "[/ ]"))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]   [,4]      [,5]  
#[1,] "17" "09" "2019" "9:15:27" "a.m."
#[2,] "17" "09" "2019" "9:15:27" "p.m."
```

Comment: This is what I have used in the end. Thankyou heaps! Gave me exactly what I needed and no errors etc!